# Debugging memory usage in D

Tags: memory-management, memory-leaks, valgrind, d

I've written a program in D which makes heavy use of pointers, as well as `std.container.Array` and `std.container.BinaryHeap`, along with a bunch of structs I have written myself, to implement a treelike structure. All of my pointers are returned either using `new` or by aliasing existing pointers.

I'm trying to test the program, which involves running the same operation many times (1000 or so), which involves allocating and deallocating quite large trees of structs inside a loop (binary trees with 100,000 leaves or so).

I'm finding that this is causing *huge* memory leaks, by which I mean 6+ GB of RAM being consumed (before the program crashes). I'm a bit baffled as to why. I've tried using Valgrind to find the source of the problem, but it's not being particularly helpful, as it can't demangle D names, so I can't even see what's leaking.

Could anyone suggest how I can begin to tackle this problem? I'm not used to this kind of thing in a high-level language. I use GDC with GCC 4.9.1 to compile my code, with `-O3 -g -pg -frelease` as compiler options.

Comment: Are you sure that you're actually leaking memory? Depending on what you're doing, you could accidentally holding on to references, making it so that the GC can't free that memory, which could lead the memory increasing like that if you're doing a lot of allocations.

Comment: @JonathanMDavis: I declare the variable that holds the tree reference inside the loop, which means (I assume) that once the loop body completes, it will be garbage collected. AFAIK, I don't hold on to any references.

Comment: Well, I find it _very_ hard to believe that you have an actual memory leak if you're using GC-allocated memory (though it's not necessarily impossible). What's more likely is that the GC is having a problem with false pointers and thinks that some of the memory that you're using holds pointers to memory which should be ready be collected, and so it won't collect it. That's much more likely on 32-bit systems than 64-bit systems, though with 6+GB of RAM, I'd expect you to be on 64-bit. Regardless, it would be a lot easier to help you if we had some sample code to look at and test out.